# Mocking a python class which changes an instance variable after a method call?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've some code where a call to the method `update()` changes the values of some instance variables. I use the changed value to leave a loop. Here is simplified example of my code:

```
def do_stuff(self):
    # get a new instance of A
    a = get_a()
    while True:
        a.update()
        if a.state == 'state':
            break
```

This a simple version of the class (I can't change the class, because it's 3rd party library):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = ''

    def update(self):
        # call to external system
        self.state = extern_func()
```

Now I want to test my function `do_stuff()` by mocking class A. To test every aspect of the function I want to have all the different values of `state` and it should changing after each call of `a.update()` (iterate over the different states).

I started with this set up for my unit test:

```
from mock import Mock, patch
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestClass):

    @patch('get_a')
    def test_do_stuff(self, mock_get_a):
         mock_a = Mock(spec=A)
         mock_get_a.return_value = mock_a

         # do some assertions
```

Can I achieve that kind behaviour with `Mock`?
I know that `Mock` has `side_effect` to return different value for consecutive function calls. But I can't figure out a way to change a value of an instance variable after a function call?

Comment: Is it possible to keep A as it is and mock the external function? That seems the easiest way to iterate over the states as you can indeed use `side_effect` to have it return each of the states.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: What you are proposing is possible, but goes against the recommendation [Where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: It doesn't go against that recommendation; in fact, it follows it as you need to patch the object in the location where it's used. That only changes depending on how `external_func` is imported (but we can't see that in your example). If it would be `import mymodule` and `mymodule.external_func()` then you'd need to change the patching to include `mymodule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
from mock import Mock, MagicMock, patch

sep = '***********************\n'

# non-mock mocks
def get_a():
    return A()
def extern_func():
    return 'foo'

def do_stuff(self):
    # get a new instance of A
    a = get_a()
    while True:
        a.update()
        print a.state
        if a.state == 'state':
            break

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = ''

    def update(self):
        # call to external system
        self.state = extern_func()
```

#### As @Simeon Viser mentioned, mocking `extern_func` would work:

```
print sep, 'patch extern'
mock = MagicMock(side_effect = [1,2,3,4, 'state'])
@patch('__main__.extern_func', mock)
def foo():
    do_stuff(3)
foo()

>>> 
***********************
patch extern
1
2
3
4
state
```

#### `side_effect` can be a function and you can mock the unbound method `A.update` using the `auto_spec = True` argument.

#### Using a context manager:

```
print sep, 'patch update context manager call do_stuff'
def update_mock(self):
    self.state = mock()
mock = MagicMock(side_effect = [1,2,3,4, 'state'])
with patch.object(A, 'update', autospec = True) as mock_update:
    mock_update.side_effect = update_mock
    do_stuff(3)

>>>
***********************
patch update context manager call do_stuff
1
2
3
4
state
```

#### Using a decorator:

```
print sep, 'patch update decorator test_do_stuff'
def update_mock(self):
    self.state = mock()
mock = MagicMock(side_effect = [1,2,3,4, 'state'])
@patch.object(A, 'update', autospec = True, side_effect = update_mock)
def test_do_stuff(self):
    do_stuff(3)
test_do_stuff()

>>>
***********************
patch update decorator test_do_stuff
1
2
3
4
state
```

Caveat:  I've never written *comprehensive* unit tests and only recently started reading the mock docs, so even though I seemed to have made this work I can't comment on it's efficacy in your testing scheme.  Edits welcome.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to @SimeonVisser your solution goes against the recommendation [Where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch). But so far it looks like the only possible solution. I will try to get my test running and let you know about my findings.

Comment: ... That isn't a recommendation, it is describing *how* you reference the object you are patching - you have to follow those instructions.  In my examples, the objects being patched and the *test/mocking* code are in the same module.